# How to set QPalette ColorRole properties with stylesheets

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

I am using a pretty lightweight custom palette that just defines a few colors and properties. I am attempting to transform it into a stylesheet but I am running into problems. For example, what is the `QPalette::Base` equivalent in stylesheets? Do I have to change the background color for every widget individually?

I tried setting a few stylesheet properties for the `QWidget` but then I got undesired results for widgets with borders. Layouts were showing borders when I didn't want them to, so I found myself writing a lot of stylesheet definitions to add/remove borders.

The gist of the question is, is there a good way to convert a palette to a stylesheet?

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote?

Comment: style sheets are a lot more powerful than palettes. One thing to keep in mind (which probably accounts for your undesired results) is that changing one thing in a style sheet usually blows away the rest of the widgets default style. So, make sure you set ALL the relevant properties for your widget, not just the one you want to change. Once you get used to doing that, it will save you a LOT of hassle in the long run.